# Awkward email flow for help desk / customer service in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I am implementing an helpdesk for a client of mine in CRM2011. However, I have some questions regarding the standard OOB email to queue flow, it seems to be off a bit, and i would like you to see if i miss something, before i start hammering away with custom development.

**The desired flow is as follows (from the UI client):**

1. A client mails to myhelpdesk@mycompany.com
2. CRM adds this to the helpdesk queue.
3. A customer service employee looks at the queue and assigns the emails he can pick up to himself.
4. Sets the regarding on the incoming email. (this is not possible field is read-only)
5. Saves the email
6. Hits reply, and sends an answer (send fromt he helpdesk address, this doesnt happen so i fixed it using a JS that replacing it onload of the reply form)
7. The mail get send tot the client.

**HOWEVER (Now it comes)**

1. The emails that enter the queue are closed, so its not possible to set the regarding trough the CRM web UI, thus, the initial emails are never assigned to the regarding entity.
2. It is not possible to add a condition to a workflow when an queue item is created to check for the "FROM" of the email since the lookup form only displays users, and not accounts, or contacts.
3. It's very hard to see the past email communication or activities with that client. First, a email enters, then it needs to click on the regarding. Then check the activities, (seeing only one line per activity) and then need to click every individual activity to check the details. Looks like a lot of clicks and overhead to me.

Anyone have the same experience? Or does anyone know a good helpdesk add-on for CRM2011?

Comment: All emails are always closed once sent or received. Emails which are received can still be "set regarding" even though they are closed. Check the user's security roles allow them to append activities which they do not own.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you consider using cases.  When an incoming activity is in the queue - you can easily convert to a case - from where you can set the fields and use it to keep a history of communications in that case.

We have setup workflows to send notifications on completion of tasks - with the original ticket requester getting copies of the notes from the task.